# How do I remove the first line of a textarea with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `textarea` here http://jsfiddle.net/ncm4not5/8/

How do I remove the first line of text from it with JQuery?

I tried:

```
$('textarea').content().first().remove();
```

and it didn't work

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var newText = $('textarea').val().replace(/^.*\n/g,"");
    $('textarea').val(newText);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncm4not5/10/)

Comment: This does not remove the first line if it's only one line remaining.

Answer (score 4):

You can split the value of the `textarea` into an array by line breaks using `.split("\n")` (I used regex in my code below to remove multiple line breaks at once), remove the first array item with `.shift()`, combine the remaining elements using `.join("\n")` and put them back into the textarea value with `.val()`.

```
var value = $("textarea").val().split(/\n+/g);
value.shift();
$("textarea").val(value.join("\n"));
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/ob763wL8/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Can use `val(fn)`

```
$('textarea').val(function(_, val){    
    return val.split('\n').slice(1).join('\n');
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/epr2w0p0/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
lines.splice(0, 1);
$('textarea').val(lines.join("\n"));
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/j0vrbLjp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the substring, and indexOf("\n") :

```
var yourText = $("#myArea").html();
var firstLineIndex = yourText.indexOf("\n");
var finalText = yourText.substring(firstLineIndex,yourText.length);
alert(finalText);
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7v4sr2Lg/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I updated you fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ncm4not5/11/

```
var lines = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML.split('\n');
var temp = '';
for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
    temp += lines[i] + '\n';
}
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Sam Aleksov's answer adjusted to also remove the last line, and a better JSFiddle with a button to remove lines.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7tf8sd0/)**

```
var currText = $('#mytextarea').val();
var newText = '';
var hasNewline = /\r|\n/.exec(currText);
if (hasNewline){
  newText = currText.replace(/^.*\n/g,"");
}
$('#mytextarea').val(newText);
```